# Changing data-src value using jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following line of code:

```
tpj("#totalcostinclship").empty().append( "<span data-src='"+pricefinal+"' id='totalcostinclship'></span>" ).text(pricefinal);
```

It first empties the existing element and then appends the new element. `pricefinal` in this case contains `245` but when I inspect my HTML, this is what I see:

```
<span data-src="220" id="totalcostinclship">245</span>
```

The `.text` is applied but the `data-src` not at all. Why could that be? `220` is the value of the data-src on page load, so before any jQuery event is started.

Comment: Assuming `tpj` is a reference to jQuery, then I am unable to replicate your problem. The given code works absolutely fine: https://jsfiddle.net/q29Lgwu5/. I can only assume you have some other logic which affects the data attribute after you append the new element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var pricefinal = 245;
var tpj = $.noConflict();

tpj("#totalcostinclship").empty().append("<span data-src='" + pricefinal + "' id='totalcostinclship'></span>").text(pricefinal);
tpj("#totalcostinclship").attr('data-src',pricefinal);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="totalcostinclship"></div>
```

Add this line

```
tpj("#totalcostinclship").attr('data-src',pricefinal);
```

after your js. Like this ->

```
tpj("#totalcostinclship").empty().append( "<span data-src='"+pricefinal+"' id='totalcostinclship'></span>" ).text(pricefinal);
tpj("#totalcostinclship").attr('data-src',pricefinal);
```

Comment: Thank you, this did the job!